# Tap power from 3D printer PSU to a Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: power-supply, power, raspberry-pi, converter, 5v

Would it be possible to power a Raspberry Pi 4 by tapping some power from the PSU of an Elegoo Neptune 3 Plus printer? Since the Raspberry Pi requires 5V to run I understand that I would have to get a converter to lower the voltage.
[image: PSU]
If its possible, where would I tap positive and ground?
Many thanks, Forcalon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V+ and V- of the 24 Volt supply is well, 24 Volts DC.

Very confusingly, L and N (mains AC power) are also red and black wires - these should be black and white in the US or brown and blue in the UK - just to prevent an answer of "connect to the red and black wires" being horribly and dangerously wrong.

You'll need a DC-DC "buck" converter to change that 24 V into 5 V.  That has to be rated for an output current that is more than what the Pi would draw, which if I remember correctly is 3 Amperes but double-check to make sure.  So a 5 A unit should work well.

Comment: you can get lots of ready-made buck converters designed for RVs/vanlife that can handle 24v in and spit out 5v for USB.